# Log MySQL login attempts

Tags: mysql, logging, login

From time to time there are failed login attempts in our MySQL production server (MySQL dashboard alerts us).  Is there a way to log every single success and failed login to the MySQL server without enabling `general_log`?

We think `general_log` is not an option due it's a production server with high load.

Comment: Consider using MariaDB Audit plugin https://mariadb.com/resources/blog/activating-auditing-mariadb-and-mysql-5-minutes
https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/about-the-mariadb-audit-plugin/

Comment: According to mysql official: `As of MySQL 5.5.28, MySQL Enterprise Edition includes MySQL Enterprise Audit, implemented using a server plugin named audit_log. ` Only enterprising version has it.

Answer (score 26):

just to inform the curious one: dig in your error log and presto!

## Edit `my.cnf` (Settings documentation found [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-options.html))

### MySQL 5

```
[mysqld]

#Enter a name for the error log file. Otherwise a default name will be used.

log_error   = /var/log/mysql/error

#defaults to 1. If the value is > 1, aborted connections and access-denied errors for new connection attempts are written to the error log

log_warnings    = 2

...
```

### MySQL 8

The name of the config variable changed; edit the same file, but add

```
log_error_verbosity=2
```

## Restart MySQL Server

Restart mysql (e.g. on systems using `systemd`):

```
# e.g. on Ubuntu the mysql server service name is "mysql"
sudo systemctl restart mysql
```

## Search the log file for failed login attempts

`$ sudo cat /var/log/mysql/error.err | egrep '[aA]ccess denied'`

And you have it!

## Restricting a user

If you need to restrict the user (dos attack or mysql user password recovering attempt in a multi user database), then (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/user-resources.html)

```
mysql> GRANT USAGE ON * . * TO 'attacker'@'localhost' WITH MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_HOUR 100;
```

to restrict to only 100 password recovering attempts per hour.

Comment: MySQL 8.0 now uses "log_error_verbosity" instead of "log_warnings". Levels are 1=ERROR, 2=ERROR, WARNING, and 3=ERROR, WARNING, INFORMATION

Answer (score 4):

I think the general log might log all login attempts (success and fail) among a lot of other things. The main problem is that the general log will affect your database's performance. You can turn on the general log with the query

```
SET GLOBAL general_log = 'on'
```

for newer versions of MySQL.

Comment: This is temporary or permanent?, if it is temporary that means that i need to modify `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` of mysql?

Comment: It is temporary. That approach can work, or you can add `--general-log` to the flags when you start MySQL.

Answer (score 2):

One can log `connect` and `quit` command by using mysql-audit-plugin.

1. Find the right version from [mysql-audit-plugin release](https://bintray.com/mcafee/mysql-audit-plugin/release#files), I used mysql 5.7, so I used `audit-plugin-percona-5.7-1.1.7-805-linux-x86_64.zip`.
2. relocate the downloaded `so` file to the place given by `mysqladmin variables | grep plugin_dir`.
3. `mysql>install plugin audit soname 'libaudit_plugin.so'`
4. turning on log function, `mysql>set global audit_json_file=ON`, by default it logs all successful operations. by setting `set global audit_record_cmds='quit,connect'` it logs only connects and quits I suppose, according to [mysql-audit-plugin configuration](https://github.com/mcafee/mysql-audit/wiki/Configuration).

This is how it looks in file for login and logout:

```
{"msg-type":"activity","date":"1543740612328","thread-id":"1015112","query-id":"3045222","user":"root","priv_user":"skip-grants user","ip":"172.28.15.10","host":"172.28.15.10","connect_attrs":{"_os":"Linux","_client_name":"libmysql","_pid":"11575","_client_version":"5.6.40","_platform":"x86_64","program_name":"mysql"},"cmd":"Quit","query":"Quit"} 

{"msg-type":"activity","date":"1543740724627","thread-id":"1015113","query-id":"0","user":"root","priv_user":"skip-grants user","ip":"172.28.15.10","host":"172.28.15.10","connect_attrs":{"_os":"Linux","_client_name":"libmysql","_pid":"11863","_client_version":"5.6.40","_platform":"x86_64","program_name":"mysql"},"cmd":"Connect","query":"Connect"}
{"msg-type":"activity","date":"1543740724629","thread-id":"1015113","query-id":"3045223","user":"root","priv_user":"skip-grants user","ip":"172.28.15.10","host":"172.28.15.10","connect_attrs":{"_os":"Linux","_client_name":"libmysql","_pid":"11863","_client_version":"5.6.40","_platform":"x86_64","program_name":"mysql"},"rows":"1","status":"0","cmd":"select","query":"select @@version_comment limit 1"}
```

Comment: And where can we find the files?

Comment: @f4d0 You mean so file? `mysql-audit-plugin-release` refers to a link. I downloaded from there. If that link is not available anymore, perhaps you can google zip file.

Comment: I mean the file that contains the login and logout entries (json look like). It is the last example you add to your answer.

Comment: @f4d0 it should be located in the same folder as table data. Or maybe you can search for it by `find . -name "mysql-audit.json"` unless you changed json file name.

Comment: Thanks @Tiina, very useful. :)

Answer (score 1):

Hi I don't think it's possible.

As of mysql 5.1.29 - you can specify storage option (table or file) and location and which log you want - error, general, binary or slow query. As far as I know - you can't specify format of the log or what gets logged. I might be wrong - but I think that all login attemps will be logged in general log, and not the error one.

However, assuming your mysql server is running on a separate machine, from you applicaiton server, and you need port 3306 ( or whatever) open and you can't use ssh tunnel, you mysql server still shouldn't be accessible by anyone willy-nilly. I highly recommend not to expose it to web traffic, and if you must ( like in case of the residing somewhere not behind your firewall) bind it to the ip address or ip block of you application server and your admin access ip ( where you are accessing from)

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

if the server in question shouldn't have external connections, as configured, I would be worried about some sort of attack against your app server, unless the failed logins are from new applications being rolled out before the user/pass has been configured.

if the server is somehow exposed to outside connections on 3306, unless that is intentional and needed, i would set the configuration as Nick said, and also look at using iptables to restrict traffic to 3306 from just your app servers.

Comment: MySQL automatically denies connections from IP address that don't have at least one matching row in mysql.user

Answer (score 0):

At http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2008/11/07/poor-mans-query-logging/ , the author shows a method to capture the packets using tcpdump , and filtering the output based on the string.

This works around your concerns regarding the general_log and performance, although tcpdump might itself incur a minor performance penalty. This solution will also log less data then the General Query Log.

I haven't used this myself, but it sounds very useful.

Comment: Sounds good, but the link does't work for me.

Comment: The link works for me this morning, using Firefox.

http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2008/11/07/poor-mans-query-logging/

Comment: And I would be interested in hearing your experience with this.